# Typescript - Argument of type 'string | (string | null)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting a typescript error from the following code:

```
if (this.$route?.query?.domainName) {
  this.setDomain(this.$route.query.domainName);
}
```

The above code throws the following error:

> Typescript - Argument of type 'string | (string | null)[]' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'string'

```
 if (this.$route?.query?.domainName) {
   this.setDomain(this.$route.query.domainName);
                  ^
 }
```

My setDomain function just accepts a parameter of type string like so:

```
setDomain(domain: string) {
  this.domainName = domain;
}
```

I don't understand how the parameter could ever be null as I am checking the object property exists using the nested `?` after the object properties in the if statement. Why would it be throwing this error?

Comment: Your argument is still a nullable string, but your method only accepts a non-nullable string as parameter. You would need to cast your argument to a non-nullable string before passing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `domainName` could still be something other than a string - an array (`(string | null)[]`). Your conditional guard is only verifying that it's not a falsey value, not that it's a string.

If you check that it's a string, it should work. Note that this example will allow an empty string, which your current code won't.

```
declare const $route: null | { query: null | { domainName: null | string | (string | null)[] } }
declare const setDomain: (domain: string) => void;

if ($route?.query?.domainName) {
    // reproduces your error
    setDomain($route.query.domainName);
}

if (typeof $route?.query?.domainName == "string") {
    // no error
    setDomain($route.query.domainName);
}
```

[See in the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gEhkgrhiAFzwr4QTwA+8A3vAI74gwCep5lN98wSAWygBLFADkoAkmQpVamGKIDmPABQLlPLhACUAbQC68AL4mAUKEiwEydFjQgMAEUEiUpVfyGjSGlEp14AF4APngANyRhYABuMzNhADN4VVwCIgB+ADpmVjZsrzcJKUC6MwBIAHpK+DgABzxgfDAQNHg2Ahh4VjwYCodnV1FUvEIQHJZ2LMLRYpAdOON4pJSMNjqQJGS0sezc9gKh8UkEIKD4ACI-JQvSiuqyJG6YXv7HF28UEfTx-bZpo5zBZmYxAA)